# Scala mass URL download

Tags: http, scala, concurrency

I've recently taken an interest in learning Scala (mostly working through Project Euler at the moment), and I've decided on a simple program I want to write: A simple concurrent downloader. I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around a good way to do it.

I know Python well, and I like the way the gevent library works. What I'd like to do is solved with gevent [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcKqyn-gUbY). Is there a simple way to do something like this in Scala, or am I totally heading down the wrong path? I've looked at the Dispatch library, but it seems incomprehensible. Should I be using Actors?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Except for the fact that the author still not managed to find time to put up the proper documentation after the latest big upgrade.

Comment: It would be fine if Dispatch didn't have such weird syntax. That makes the lack of proper documentation more frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I do agree that [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) documentation is a bit rough and small at the moment, but that'll probably change in the future (and it is the situation with many great Scala libs).

But the result of applying Dispatch for your need is spectacular:

```
import dispatch._
(1 to 100).map{ i => 
   Http(url("http://bash.org/?" + i) OK as.String) 
}.map{ f => 
  try {Some(f.apply)} catch {case e => println(e.getMessage); None}
}.seq.flatten
```

This would get you files for first 100 quotes from `bash.org`, in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, this kind of example is incredibly helpful!

Comment: You don't need the parallel collection with Dispatch 0.9.0, because all URL requests will be processed in parallel, and the mappings called asynchronously. I bet the overhead of parallel collections will surpass the gains. Instead, do everything as usual, and then use `Promise.all` to convert the iterable of promises into a promise of iterables, and then apply.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - And how would Promise.all deal with exceptions? Would it fail completely, if it would get exception from one of underlying promises?

Comment: @Rogach Good question! No clue. :-) I suspect it would fail completely. On the other hand, if you call `either` or `option` on each `Http`, then you'll get an iterable of `Either` or `Option`, doing away with this problem.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - Yes, that'll be better - but I think for "educational" purposes this version will be more obvious.